# Chmod breaks folder access / file access

Tags: chmod

My servers are currently running a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 server, no direct nor indirect system changes have been made.

A folder/file is completely accessible when created, but if I use `chmod` to make the slightest change, I completely lose access to that folder, and the only way to access it is through root.

`sudo chmod -r -777` will make the folder completely useless, and there is no way for me to access it.

Answer (score 5):

By `chmod -777` you set the access rights to `---------` i.e. you remove all access rights. Try `chmod 777` and your file or folder will be accessible again.

Comment: Nicely caught :-)

Comment: I can`t belive i missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Normally you should avoid `777` though. Rather go for e.g. `755` or `644` (depending on whether it should be executable/is a directory or not) to restrict write permissions for other users except the owner.